# Calculating complex integral representation of the Hankel function of the first kind

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

I was wondering if any one can help me calculate this integral using Mathematica.
This is a form of integral representation of Hankel function of first kind:

```
(-1)^n/(I Pi[]) *
 Integrate[ Exp[-k r (Sinh[t] Cos[tt]] + I Cosh[t] Sin[tt])] Exp[-n t],
     {t,-Infinity, 0, PI[] I, Infinity + PI[] I}, PrincipalValue -> True])
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code. But apart from that, MA does not know much about the contour integrals.

Comment: The Integrate function is not going to integrate that along three separate contours as you seem to wish above.   Need to integrate over separate contours or parameterize the contours via a Piecewise function if possible.    It's not difficult to integrate it numerically or just use the built-in HankelH1 function.